# Do certain workouts damage our neck for singing?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, voice-training, vocal-cords

I am 19 years old boy , and a beginner in singing , inspired by artists like One-Republic , Conor Maynard ... I'm no old in online singing courses (like 5 months) , but I've been practicing some specific workouts for years .
Certain workouts like Pull-ups , Crunch , Bi-cycle crunch etc. have affected the muscles around my neck . I have to pressure my neck on above workouts on daily basis . Hene , My neck is tight and bigger in shape than normal person ...
So with due respect ,
Do doing workouts involving neck damage my vocal ability to singing , or ability to move it in certain direction for perfect note ?
My vocal range gives up on highs notes like in " Someday - One-Republic" , "someone you loved - Lewis Capaldi" etc. Which is normal pitch for most of the singers .
I often struggle to control and shake my voice (like "Connor Maynard - Stitches ) .. Is it the reason I'm not able to sing as I will ? I hope my question will be answered .Thank you

Comment: You might want to consult a doctor and or voice teacher. Being neither of those, but being someone who has both worked out and sang for many years, I doubt that hypertrophy of the neck muscles will cause a problem. Also it’s normal to not be able to "sing as you will" after only five months. I’d give yourself 2-5 years to start feeling very confident in singing. One workout thing that has affected my voice is breathing wrong and/or grunting (when lifting). Be careful you aren’t accidentally vocalizing when you breathe, and if you count reps, whisper your counting.

Comment: In addition to emphasizing everything @ToddWilcox wrote, if you need to adjust your head position to sing specific notes, then there's a good chance your technique needs refinement, and for that an experienced and knowledgeable teacher is an unequivocal requirement. A teacher (or, possibly, a physical trainer) will also help with any breathing-related issues that may develop by improper breathing during your exercises.

Comment: @ToddWilcox thank you sir for responding ... I do practice breathe exercises ( eg. "Nadi Suddhi , Anulam-bilam ..) as a part of my morning yoga . So I think breathing should not not be a problem for me .. I can freely breath , fully in and fully out ,  as slow and gentle as possible . Tho , I haven't learnt about breath technique for singing for now ...

Comment: @Todd I had a doubt , as we do certain workouts , our neck gets tight in muscles and bigger in shape ...  So can you sing with ease without pressuring neck ? Do you feel your neck less flexible than others ? I think most of the singers don't go to gym , hard workouts... Instead they prefer breathing , yoga , diets etc. The hard-workout guys rather seen in Raps , hip-hops ..

Comment: Extrapolate your theory further. Take such as body-builders or even Formula 1 racing drivers, who have massive neck muscles in comparison to their size. If the muscle structure grew 'inwards' as they gained mass… they eventually wouldn't be able to speak or even breathe properly. I used to do a lot of weight training around the same time as I was a session singer - never noticed any difference in performance.

Comment: One basic thing to point out: everyone has a different range. Just because you can't hit the same note as someone else is not necessarily a problem. And everyone can train their voice to some degree; you're challenged by "shaking your voice" (vibrato), but this can be taught and learned over time.

Comment: @Andy thanks man , I got your point ... I can do low tempo vibrato like classical slow musics like in church ... But I can't do the ones like Conor Maynard does , they are very controlled and fast .. I lose shaking in that fast movement

Comment: The serious singers I've known seemed to focus on aerobic exercise (e.g. walking, running, treadmill, cycling, etc.) more than weightlifting.  I wonder if it might be helpful to adjust your work-out routine a bit.  But really, the most important thing is to get a medical check-up and bring up your concerns with the doctor.